# Find Sessions Connected by IP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there anyway to see which address connections are connecting on?

More info:

I've repeatedly found people setting up connectionstrings using IP instead of by DNS name, and with SQL2012 and above, connecting to instances by server name without including the instance name (i.e. where this is on port 1433).
I'd like to audit this so that within hours of something having connected using a non-compliant connection string, I can be alerted and so quickly find the culprit and fix the issue; as opposed to waiting for changes in infrastructure (e.g. us moving to a non-standard port, or switching to a different host on a different IP whilst maintaining the same underlying DNS entry) to cause more serious surprises as a result of non-compliant configurations.

Comment: I don't think SQL Server knows what IP/name was originally used by the client in order to connect. You would have to detect that at some lower layer.

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand; that's my suspicion, but hopefully we'll be contradicted...

Comment: FYI: `select * from sys.dm_exec_connections` has a column, `local_net_address` which gives the IP of the local server (or rather, of the DNS entry used to reach the local server; which may be different where a cluster's used).  Not quite what I'm after, but may be helpful to others finding this post.

Comment: I don't think that's what you're after. From [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181509.aspx): "Represents the IP address on the server that this connection targeted. Available only for connections using the TCP transport provider." It won't tell you what name they used to get that IP resolved or whether they explicitly specified a port, and it will be null if they used named pipes to connect.

Comment: I've been messing around with WireShark trying to read the encrypted payload to see if the algo used maintains the same encrypted values based on what is used to connect in the string.  I might have to use winpcap or something that really let's me look at the payload though, so far no luck.

Comment: FYI: Submitted as a feature suggestion on MS Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3105620

Comment: A suggestion for finding these would be to change the port on the next maintenance cycle, taking care to alert the relevant parties that the change was going to happen and that they should use the named instance.  Then change it again on the following maintenance cycle and see who really listened.  You could use some of the other suggestions to identify the various client machines who are connecting and attempt to specifically verify that they are connecting the way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do this.

However, MS are considering this as a feature suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32901958-view-client-connection-properties-from-the-server

If this is something you want; please upvote the above.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
SELECT session_id, client_net_address
    FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
```

Comment: Thanks @MSL.  Sadly that gives the client machine's IP address, rather than information about the properties of the connection string (specifically the `Server`/`Data Store` properties) they have defined.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right, this is something that cannot be retrieved.

I also checked PowerShell and I couldn't find any solution.

Sorry for my last reply which was wrong. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is the most detailed info you can retrieve as long as I know:

```
SELECT   
    c.session_id, c.net_transport, c.encrypt_option,   
    c.auth_scheme, s.host_name, s.program_name,   
    s.client_interface_name, s.login_name, s.nt_domain,   
    s.nt_user_name, s.original_login_name, c.connect_time,   
    s.login_time   
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections AS c  
JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s  
    ON c.session_id = s.session_id
```

Comment: Thanks @FrancescoMantovani.  Sadly this returns the client machine's hostname/ip address.  Rather I'm after the server's information as used by the client; i.e. essentially a copy of the client's connection string.